# How to fix start function in hangman game

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, console

I have been working on a hangman game in the console with JavaScript and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to randomly select past the first 2 categories. I know it must be an easy solution but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is my start game function where the problem is

```
function start () {


player.guessedLetters = []
  player.strikes = 0
  player.maxStrikes = 3
  player.display = []
  player.status = true
  displayIn = []



const game = Math.floor(Math.random() * (categories.length))
  if (game === 0) {
    console.log('The category is Easy Words')
    const selectEasyWords = easyWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * (6))]

player.display = selectEasyWords
for (let i = 0; i < selectEasyWords.length; i++) {
  if (selectEasyWords[i] === ' ') {
    displayIn.push(' ')
  } else {
    displayIn.push('_')
  }
}
    return ${displayIn.join(' ')}
  } else if (game === 1) {
    console.log('The category is Medium Words')
    const selectMediumWords = mediumWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * (6))]

player.display = selectMediumWords
for (let i = 0; i < selectMediumWords.length; i++) {
  if (selectMediumWords[i] === ' ') {
    displayIn.push(' ')
  } else {
    displayIn.push('_')
  }
}
return ${displayIn.join(' ')}


} else if (game === 1) {
    console.log('The category is Hard Words')
    const selectHardWords = hardWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * (6))]

player.display = selectHardWords
for (let i = 0; i < selectHardWords.length; i++) {
  if (selectHardWords[i] === ' ') {
    displayIn.push(' ')
  } else {
    displayIn.push('_')
  }
}
return ${displayIn.join(' ')}


} else if (game === 1) {
    console.log('The category is Extreme Words')
    const selectExtremeWords = extremeWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * (2))]

player.display = selectExtremeWords
for (let i = 0; i < selectExtremeWords.length; i++) {
  if (selectExtremeWords[i] === ' ') {
    displayIn.push(' ')
  } else {
    displayIn.push('_')
  }
}
return ${displayIn.join(' ')}


} else {
    return Where did you go wrong
  }
}
```

Here is the rest of my code for context.

```
    console.log('HANGMAN\nTry to solve the puzzle by guessing letters using guess(letter).\nIf you miss a letter you get a strike.\nGet 3 strikes and you lose the game.\nTo select difficulty, type difficulty(difficulty).\nDifficulties:\nEasy\nMedium\nHard\nExtreme\nTo start game type start().')

const player = {
  guessedLetters: [],
  strikes: 0,
  maxStrikes: 3,
  display: [],
  status: false
}

const easyWords = [
  'DOG',
  'CAT',
  'HELLO',
  'FISH',
  'RED',
  'FOOD'
]

const mediumWords = [
  'I LIKE THE COLOR PINK',
  'MY FISHES NAME IS BEN',
  'THE GREATEST SHOWMAN IS THE BEST MOVIE',
  'OK GOOGLE HOW TO PASS IMD',
  'I WORK AT LANDMARK CINEMAS',
  'LEGO BATMAN IS THE ONLY GOOD BATMAN MOVIE'
]

const hardWords = [
  'THIS IS AN EXAMPLE OF A HARDER PHRASE THIS PROJECT IS SO HARD',
  'IVE BEEN STARING AT THIS PROJECT FOR 4 HOURS TODAY I DONT KNOW IF I CAN DO THIS ANYMORE',
  'I REALLY MISS MY DOG HER NAME IS CASSY AND SHES A SHIH TZU AND BARKS A LOT',
  'MY FAVOURITE SONG IS CALLED MASTERPIECE THEATRE PART 3 BY MARIANAS TRENCH',
  'I BOUGHT THE HEDLEY TICKETS 5 MONTHS BEFORE THE ALLEGATIONS CAME OUT',
  'CAN SOMEONE PLEASE HELP ME WITH THIS PROJECT OH  MY GOD'
]

const extremeWords = [
  'LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT, SED DO EIUSMOD TEMPOR INCIDIDUNT UT LABORE ET DOLORE MAGNA ALIQUA. UT ENIM AD MINIM VENIAM, QUIS NOSTRUD EXERCITATION ULLAMCO LABORIS NISI UT ALIQUIP EX EA COMMODO CONSEQUAT. DUIS AUTE IRURE DOLOR IN REPREHENDERIT IN VOLUPTATE VELIT ESSE CILLUM DOLORE EU FUGIAT NULLA PARIATUR. EXCEPTEUR SINT OCCAECAT CUPIDATAT NON PROIDENT, SUNT IN CULPA QUI OFFICIA DESERUNT MOLLIT ANIM ID EST LABORUM',
  'According to all known laws of aviation, there is no way a bee should be able to fly. Its wings are too small to get its fat little body off the ground. The bee, of course, flies anyway because bees don`t care what humans think is impossible. Yellow, black. Yellow, black. Yellow, black. Yellow, black.'
]

const categories = ['Easy Words', 'Medium Words', 'Hard Words', 'Extreme Words']

let displayIn = []

function start () {
  player.guessedLetters = []
  player.strikes = 0
  player.maxStrikes = 3
  player.display = []
  player.status = true
  displayIn = []

  const game = Math.floor(Math.random() * (categories.length))
  if (game === 0) {
    console.log('The category is Easy Words')
    const selectEasyWords = easyWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * (6))]

    player.display = selectEasyWords
    for (let i = 0; i < selectEasyWords.length; i++) {
      if (selectEasyWords[i] === ' ') {
        displayIn.push(' ')
      } else {
        displayIn.push('_')
      }
    }
    return ${displayIn.join(' ')}
  } else if (game === 1) {
    console.log('The category is Medium Words')
    const selectMediumWords = mediumWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * (6))]

    player.display = selectMediumWords
    for (let i = 0; i < selectMediumWords.length; i++) {
      if (selectMediumWords[i] === ' ') {
        displayIn.push(' ')
      } else {
        displayIn.push('_')
      }
    }
    return ${displayIn.join(' ')}
  } else if (game === 1) {
    console.log('The category is Hard Words')
    const selectHardWords = hardWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * (6))]

    player.display = selectHardWords
    for (let i = 0; i < selectHardWords.length; i++) {
      if (selectHardWords[i] === ' ') {
        displayIn.push(' ')
      } else {
        displayIn.push('_')
      }
    }
    return ${displayIn.join(' ')}
  } else if (game === 1) {
    console.log('The category is Extreme Words')
    const selectExtremeWords = extremeWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * (2))]

    player.display = selectExtremeWords
    for (let i = 0; i < selectExtremeWords.length; i++) {
      if (selectExtremeWords[i] === ' ') {
        displayIn.push(' ')
      } else {
        displayIn.push('_')
      }
    }
    return ${displayIn.join(' ')}
  } else {
    return Where did you go wrong
  }
}

function guess (letter) {
  if (player.status) {
    if (displayIn.indexOf('_') !== -1) {
      if (player.strikes < player.maxStrikes) {
        const value = letter.toUpperCase()
        player.guessedLetters.push(value)
        const arrayPuzzle = player.display
        if (arrayPuzzle.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
          for (let d = arrayPuzzle.indexOf(value); d < player.display.length; d++) {
            if (arrayPuzzle.indexOf(value) !== -1 && arrayPuzzle[d] === value) {
              displayIn[d] = value
            }
          }
          if (displayIn.indexOf('_') !== -1) {
            console.log(There are ${value}s in the phrase.)
            return ${displayIn.join(' ')}
          } else {
            player.status = false
            console.log(${displayIn.join(' ')})
            return Congrats. You won!!!!
          }
        } else {
          player.strikes++
          if (player.strikes === player.maxStrikes) {
            player.status = false
            return You ran out of strikes. G A M E  O V E R
          } else {
            return This letter is non existant.
          }
        }
      } else {
        player.status = false
        return You ran out of strikes.  G A M E  O V E R.
      }
    } else {
      player.status = false
      console.log(${displayIn.join(' ')})
      return Congrats U WON!!!
    }
  } else {
    return Please start the game.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question then this approach might work: What you need is an array of arrays so imagine

```
var gameModes=[
    ['EasyWords','AnotherEasy'],['MediumWords'],['HardWords']
]
```

Now to select the category you can do as you have:

```
let game=Math.floor(Math.random() * (gameModes.length))
```

Then to select a word

```
function SelectWord(wordList)
{ 
 let wordIndex=Math.floor(Math.random() * (wordList.length))
 return wordList[wordIndex];
}
```

Now you can call this function as

```
let word=SelectWord(gameModes[game]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `game` is assigned from

```
const game = Math.floor(Math.random() * (categories.length))
```

and since `categories.length` is 4, you will always get a value of either 0, 1, 2, or 3. Afterwards, your `if...else if` statements evaluate `game === 1` and not changing to `game === 2` or `game === 3` so it'll never find the other word categories. In addition, I'd suggest `switch` rather than all the if statements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch